# How to load test a registration of account in JMeter?

Tags: parameters, jmeter, registration, creation

I would like to ask on how to do a load test using JMeter for registration of account? The requests are already setup on my local with random email and password parameters, then after running the test run it is successful. Unfortunately, when validating the created users, no new user was even created. Is there anyone that can help me with this issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> then after running the test run it is successful

your assumption is wrong. If you don't see any errors it doesn't necessarily mean that the request is not successful. JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful and doesn't check response data.

A simple example of a pseudo-successful request of [JMeter Bugzilla login](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html):

[image]

So if you need to additionally check the presence of content specific for the registered user like "Success" message or "Welcome" text - add [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) to the request and put your pass/fail criteria there.

In the absolutely majority of cases JMeter scripts are not doing what they're supposed to be doing due to:

- Missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters
- [Missing HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)